# Graphviz: Changing node spacing within a subgraph cluster

Tags: graphviz

Experienced but no expert in Graphviz.

The example code and image that I am sharing is part of a larger graph, I pulled this out to make the question and example clearer.

The graph is rank separated and is flowing from left to right. In the image example you see three of the ranks and nodes space nicely but I want to tighten them in the subgraph.

I have tried a half dozen syntactical options but none of them allow me to shrink the vertical distance between nodes in the subgraph and no where else.

Not sure how to isolate the nodesep to just the subgraph cluster.

Thank you for any help.

[image: Sample subgraph]

```
digraph G {
    
    graph   [rankdir=LR, ranksep=.8, nodesep=.25];
    edge    [dir=forward, color=black];
    node    [shape=rectangle, fontsize=12, fontname="Times-Roman", height=.45];
    
    {edge [color=firebrick1]    v_Automobile    ->{"Locational"; "Consumption"; "Governmental"};};
    {edge [color=blue2]         v_Body          ->{"BioMetric"; "Networked IoT"; "Medical"};};
    {edge [color=darkviolet]    v_Citizen       ->{"Associative"; "Conversaional"; "Governmental"; "Political"};};
    {edge [color=lightskyblue]  v_Consumer      ->{"Consumption"; "Educational"; "Employment"; "Governmental"; "Locational"; "Medical"; "Transactional"};};
    {edge [color=crimson]       v_Home          ->{"Consumption"; "Emanative"; "Locational"; "Networked IoT"};};
    
    {edge [color=blue2]         "BioMetric"     ->{SP_Camera; SP_Apps; "CCTV"};};
    {edge [color=crimson]       "Consumption"   ->"Smart Meter"};
    {edge [color=blue2]         "Medical"       ->SP_Apps};
    {edge [color=darkviolet]    "Political"     ->"Ballot"};
    {edge [color=lightskyblue]  "Transactional" ->{SP_Browser; SP_Apps; "Reward Cards"; "Paypoint"};};
    
    subgraph cluster_SmartPhone {label = "Smart Phone"; 
            dirType=none;
            SP_Apps;
            SP_Browser;
            SP_Camera;
            SP_GPS};
            
    SP_Apps             [label="Apps",
                        height=.40,
                        color=black];
    SP_Browser          [label="Browser",
                        color=black];
    SP_Camera           [label="Camera",
                        color=black];
    SP_GPS              [label="GPS",
                        color=black];
                        
    v_Automobile        [label="Automobile",
                        penwidth=2,
                        color=firebrick1];                  
    v_Body              [label="Body",
                        penwidth=2,
                        color=blue2];
    v_Citizen           [label="Citizen",
                        penwidth=2,
                        color=darkviolet];
    v_Consumer          [label="Consumer",
                        penwidth=2,
                        color=lightskyblue];
    v_Home              [label="Home",
                        penwidth=2,
                        color=crimson];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that these nodes you want to tighten are on the same rank, you may replace them with a table. In table you can remove the outer border and set the **cellspacing** attribute to control distance between cells.

To make edges to these pseudo-nodes you will have to set the **port** attribute to each cell and then reference these ports as [headport](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:headport) attribute or `node:port` syntax.

Your only inconvenience would be that you can't make edges to multiple nodes containing these pseudonodes with syntax `node1 -> {pseudonode1;pseudonode2;node3}` because **headport** is the atribute of the edge. So you'll have to state these edges separately.

Your example with this technique will look like this:

```
digraph G {

    graph   [rankdir=LR, ranksep=.8, nodesep=.25];
    edge    [dir=forward, color=black];
    node    [shape=rectangle, fontsize=12, fontname="Times-Roman", height=.45];

    {edge [color=firebrick1]    v_Automobile    ->{"Locational"; "Consumption"; "Governmental"};};
    {edge [color=blue2]         v_Body          ->{"BioMetric"; "Networked IoT"; "Medical"};};
    {edge [color=darkviolet]    v_Citizen       ->{"Associative"; "Conversaional"; "Governmental"; "Political"};};
    {edge [color=lightskyblue]  v_Consumer      ->{"Consumption"; "Educational"; "Employment"; "Governmental"; "Locational"; "Medical"; "Transactional"};};
    {edge [color=crimson]       v_Home          ->{"Consumption"; "Emanative"; "Locational"; "Networked IoT"};};

    {edge [color=blue2]         "BioMetric"     -> tight:Camera;};
    {edge [color=blue2]         "BioMetric"     -> tight:Apps;};
    {edge [color=blue2]         "BioMetric"     ->{"CCTV"};};
    {edge [color=crimson]       "Consumption"   ->"Smart Meter"};
    {edge [color=blue2]         "Medical"       ->tight:Apps};
    {edge [color=darkviolet]    "Political"     ->"Ballot"};
    {edge [color=lightskyblue]  "Transactional" -> tight:Browser};
    {edge [color=lightskyblue]  "Transactional" -> tight:Apps;};
    {edge [color=lightskyblue]  "Transactional" -> {"Reward Cards"; "Paypoint"};};

    subgraph cluster_SmartPhone {label = "Smart Phone";
            dirType=none;
            tight [
                shape=none
                label=<
                    <table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="10">
                        <tr>
                            <td port="Camera">Camera</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td port="Apps">Apps</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td port="Browser">Browser</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td port="GPS">GPS</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                >
            ]
    };


    v_Automobile        [label="Automobile",
                        penwidth=2,
                        color=firebrick1];
    v_Body              [label="Body",
                        penwidth=2,
                        color=blue2];
    v_Citizen           [label="Citizen",
                        penwidth=2,
                        color=darkviolet];
    v_Consumer          [label="Consumer",
                        penwidth=2,
                        color=lightskyblue];
    v_Home              [label="Home",
                        penwidth=2,
                        color=crimson];
}
```

Result:

[image]